# Mono VS Wine exception handling on linux

Tags: linux, exception, webdriver, mono, wine

I have my own C# software that i use and i want to transition from windows to linux. (Mint 20)

I got everything working except for the following problem:

When i run my application with mono (mono xxx.exe) all exceptions are hidden.

Also Application.ThreadException and AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException won't fire.

throw new Exception("test") won't show anything.

When i run my application with wine (wine xxx.exe) this does work like expected.

This is confusing to me, why does mono hide all exceptions? Why can't i find more info on this online? So far i can't get around this, so this would be problem 1.

As a workaround i tried using mono to develop and wine to run live.

I have the application running daily and send any exceptions to my phone.

So in case of problems i get alerted and fix it.

But this route failed as well:

I use selenium webdriver and this runs fine from mono, but from wine i get:
"cannot start the driver service on localhost:xxxx"

I do find information on this online, but the recommended solution is to use 127.0.0.1 in stead of localhost and this doesn't seem to be possible with selenium webdriver(as far as i can tell).
So this would be problem 2.

Any help would be great!

Comment: "I have my own C# software that i use and i want to transition from windows to linux. (Mint 20)". If you really want that to happen, migrate to .NET Core. Neither Mono nor Wine can help you in the right way in a tough time like this.

Comment: Did think of that, but in that case i could better wait for the upcoming .net 5 release.

Comment: No, you shouldn’t wait. .NET 5 is still upon .NET Core profile, and the migration won’t cost you less.

Comment: Does .net 4.8 to 5.0 involve the same work as .net 4.8 to core 3?

Comment: Matching .NET Framework and .NET Core API profiles was a focus during .NET Core 2.x/3.x development, but not beyond. "After .NET Core 3.0 we will not port any more features from .NET Framework." from https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/net-core-is-the-future-of-net/ So you should start migration as early as possible.

Comment: In that case you are right, thank you for the advice!